# Count rows of duplicate concatenated fields

Tags: mysql

I have a table with data:

```
    ID Version     Major       Minor       Revision
    1  00000000004 00000000000 00000000012 0000000015
    2  00000000004 00000000000 00000000012 0000000015
    3  00000000004 00000000000 00000000013 0000000001
    4  00000000004 00000000000 00000000013 0000000002
    5  00000000004 00000000000 00000000013 0000000008
    6  00000000004 00000000000 00000000013 0000000008
    7  00000000004 00000000000 00000000014 0000000007
    8  00000000004 00000000000 00000000014 0000000008
    9  00000000004 00000000000 00000000014 0000000009
    10 00000000004 00000000000 00000000014 0000000009
    11 00000000004 00000000000 00000000014 0000000009
    12 00000000004 00000000000 00000000014 0000000009
    13 00000000004 00000000000 00000000014 0000000009
    14 00000000004 00000000000 00000000014 0000000009
    15 00000000004 00000000000 00000000014 0000000010
    16 00000000004 00000000000 00000000014 0000000011
```

I want to concatenate the Version, Major, Minor and Revision fields and count the duplicate rows of the versions:

```
    DB Version   Count
    V4.0.12.15   2
    V4.0.13.01   1
    V4.0.13.02   2
    V4.0.13.08   2 
    V4.0.14.07   1
    V4.0.14.09   6
    V4.0.14.10   1
    V4.0.14.11   1
```

So far I can concatenate the DB Version using:

```
    SELECT CONCAT (
        'V'
        RIGHT(LTRIM(Version) 1)
        '.'
        RIGHT(LTRIM(Major) 1)
        '.'
        RIGHT(LTRIM(Minor) 2)
        '.'
        RIGHT(LTRIM(Revision) 2)
        ) AS 'DB Version' FROM DBversion;
```

But I am struggling with how to extract the count for the DB Versions.

Comment: What are all those zeroes? Why not store integers as integers?

Comment: If those columns are character type, I'd be using an expression like `TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM Version)`, rather than using `RIGHT(Version,n)`.

Comment: Unfortunately - all the zeroes is how the fields are stored.

Thanks for the TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM Version) tip.

Answer (score 0):

You solved the hard part.  The rest is just aggregation:

```
SELECT CONCAT(
        'V'
        RIGHT(LTRIM(Version) 1)
        '.'
        RIGHT(LTRIM(Major) 1)
        '.'
        RIGHT(LTRIM(Minor) 2)
        '.'
        RIGHT(LTRIM(Revision) 2)
        ) AS "DB Version",
       COUNT(*)
FROM DBversion
GROUP BY "DB Version";
```

Note:  don't put a space between `concat` and `(`.  MySQL doesn't like that.

Comment: SELECT CONCAT(
            'V',
            TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM Version),
            '.',
            RIGHT(LTRIM(Major), 1),
            '.',
            RIGHT(LTRIM(Minor), 2),
            '.',
            RIGHT(LTRIM(Revision), 2)
            ) AS 'DB Version',
            COUNT(*) AS Count
        FROM DBversion
        GROUP BY 'DB Version';
Gives:
        DB Version, Count
        V4.0.05.00  261

Answer (score 0):

Something like that

```
select
    version,
    count(*)
from (
    select 
        concat('V', concat_ws('.', 
            Version + 0, 
            Major + 0, 
            Minor + 0, 
            Revision + 0)
        ) version
    from DBversion
) concatenated
group by version
```

However it is highly not recommended to go this way, as such query will have very poor performance.
The better solution would be to create intermediate table, calculate the version numbers and then make a query with `group by` from that intermediate table.

Comment: Thanks - produces the desired results and I am not worried about performance as it is a small table. Next problem is to sort the results correctly.